# get good performance java excel stream reuse

Tags: java, excel

I need to do send different excel to multi person.

**Question:**

how can I Improve this code in write out excel part
I want stream reuse and move stream close out of loop
how can I achieve?

thanks for any suggest

**code like this:**

```
...............
    for (String key : manMappingSys.keySet()) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
                List<String> sysList = manMappingSys.get(key);
                Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("人員離調不須覆核清單");
                int rowNum = 0;
                // excel各欄位標題
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("離調職");
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue("資料日期");
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue("員編");
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue("應用系統代號");
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue("使用者員編");
                row.createCell(5).setCellValue("登入帳號");
                row.createCell(6).setCellValue("系統群組代號");
                row.createCell(7).setCellValue("最近登入日期");
                row.createCell(8).setCellValue("匯入日期");
                row.createCell(9).setCellValue("註記");
                rowNum++;
                for (String sysId : sysList) {
                    List<LeaveList> leaveList = sysMappingLeave.get(sysId);
                    for (LeaveList leave : leaveList) {
                        Row tempRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
                        tempRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(leave.getChangeLeave());
                        tempRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(leave.getDataDate().toString());
                        tempRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(leave.getUserId());
                        tempRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(leave.getSysNoId().getSc02ApType());
                        tempRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(leave.getSysNoId().getUsrId());
                        tempRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(leave.getSysNoId().getActNo());
                        tempRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(leave.getSysNoId().getRgroup());
                        tempRow.createCell(7).setCellValue(leave.getSysNoId().getLastDate().toString());
                        rowNum++;
                    }
                }
                wb.write(output);
                BufferedInputStream out = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray()));
                InputStreamResource rtnVal = new InputStreamResource(out, "人員離調不須覆核清單.xlsx");
                InputStreamResource[] atts = new InputStreamResource[1];
                atts[0] = rtnVal;
                // 依照系統發送相關Email
                String[] toMails = new String[1];
                SysEmployee manager = employeeMapper.getEmployeeByCn(key);
                toMails[0] = manager.getMail();
                mailService.sendMail(SCHEDULE_LEAVE_OR_TRASFER_NOTICE_NOT_TEMPLATE, new HashMap(),
                        Locale.getDefault(), toMails, atts);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(wb);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            }

................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that what you are asking your question doesn't make sense.  Let me explain.

Each iteration of the outer loop gets a `key` and then creates a spreadsheet from a list of ids obtained like this:

```
 sysList = manMappingSys.get(key);
```

Unless there is something you are not telling us ... that will result in a different spreadsheet containing different values for each loop iteration.  And indeed, this is borne out by this statement in your QuestionL

> I need to do send different excel to multi person

Therefore, you can't reuse the ByteArrayOutputStream ... because it *needs* to contain a different spreadsheet each time.

Even if the spreadsheets were mostly the same (i.e. differed in small details only), you still wouldn't be able to reuse the ByteArrayOutputStream objects.  They need to contain a serialization of the entire spreadsheet, and will therefore be different.

---

Maybe there is something else that you can tell us about this problem that will make it make more sense.

---

The other thing that strikes me is that you *may* be optimizing this on the *assumption* that creating and/or serializing the spreadsheet is the bottleneck.  That assumption could be false.  In fact, I suspect that the bottleneck will be the step where you send the email.  If you haven't done so already, I would advise **profiling** your code to find out where the performance hotspots really are.